# What is wrong with this property binding in Angular4 while using it on style property?

Tags: javascript, angular, property-binding

In Angular4, **property binding** on the view (.html) picks up the value from the logic file (.ts)

This works well in the code:

```
<img [src]="sourceValue">
```

This too works well in the code:

```
<button [disabled]="isDisabled">
```

Why does this not work?

```
<p [style]="paragraphStyle"> This is a paragraph.</p>
```

**abc.component.ts**

```
isDisabled:boolean = true; 
sourceValue:string = "./assets/hermione.jpg"; 
paragraphStyle:string = "background:red; color:yellow";
```

I know the usage of **ngStyles** and **ngClass**, I simply want to ask why property binding is not working in the above case. It is finally --- just a simple "Inline CSS Styling" if value is taken from .ts file and added to the html snippet in front of 'style' property in paragraph.

Comment: You are doing things here that you shouldn't, your TypeScript file in a component is for marshalling data between the html view and services and the html file is for presentation. If you have image names and styles in your TypeScript then you are thinking about the separation of concerns incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of security Measures:

**[`@Angular docs`](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-and-security-contexts)**
Angular defines the following security contexts:

- HTML is used when interpreting a value as HTML, for example, when
  binding to innerHtml.
- Style is used when binding CSS into the       style property.
- URL is used for URL properties, such as `<a href>.`
- Resource URL is a URL that will be loaded and executed as     code,
  for example, in `<script src>`.

The Fix is to sanitize values beforehand using  `bypassSecurityTrustStyle()`- Bypass security and trust the given value to be safe style value (CSS).

> **[`@Angular docs`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytruststyle)**
>
> > WARNING: calling this method with untrusted user data exposes your
> >     application to XSS security risks!

**Component:**

```
import { Component, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  paragraphStyle;
constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer){ 

  this.paragraphStyle=this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle("background-color:red");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p [style]="paragraphStyle"> This is a paragraph.</p>
```

**NOTE:**

> For style property name use dash-case.
>   For example, font-weight ,background-color

[`Live Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tavtvy)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it but you have to do it like so: 
`[style.background]="'red'"`

Comment: Thanks, but the question again stucks, why not just picking up value from .ts and replacing like other cases on view part? It would be a 'simple inline styling'.

Comment: Dunno but I know that it doesn't really work the way you want it has to do something with styling rules and how they apply them within Renderer. Best is just to use ngStyles or ngClass. Btw you should prefer using classes instead since inline styles don't cache in browser.

Comment: And with this method you can actually pick up the value from ts you just need to replace 'red' with property name. Like so: `[style.background]="redVariable"`

Comment: Are you getting any errors or warings?
"Technically, Angular is matching the name to a directive input, one of the property names listed in the directive's inputs array or a property decorated with @Input(). Such inputs map to the directive's own properties." --> "If the name fails to match a property of a known directive or element, Angular reports an “unknown directive” error."

Comment: @NerijusPamedytis Have a look at my answer to get a clear picture:)

Comment: Yeah I forgot about that one :)